# iteration over a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

In below code users and friendships are  dictionaries and two element touple.  The 2nd for loop

```
for i,j in friendships:
    users[i]["friends"].append(users[j])
    users[j]["friends"].append(users[i])
```

add additional "friends" key to the original users dictionary. How exactly the 
second for loop is executing to add the values for friends key?

```
users=[
            {"id":0,"name":"Hero"},
            {"id":1,"name":"Dunn"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Sue"},
            {"id":3,"name":"Chi"},
            {"id":4,"name":"Thor"},
            {"id":5,"name":"Clive"},
            {"id":6,"name":"Hicks"},
            {"id":7,"name":"Devin"},
            {"id":8,"name":"Kate"},
            {"id":9,"name":"klein"}
    ]
friendships=[(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(5,7),(6,8),(7,8),(8,9)]

for user in users:
    user["friends"]=[]
for i,j in friendships:
    users[i]["friends"].append(users[j])
    users[j]["friends"].append(users[i])
```

Comment: Google "tuple unpacking"

Answer (score 0):

> In below code users and friendships are two dictionaries

`friendships` is not a dictionary; it is a list of two-element tuples.

The loop `for i,j in friendships` takes each tuple from the list and assigns the first item in the tuple to `i` and the second item to `j`.